# In temporary tables/variables: join multiple rows to table with only 1 row

Tags: t-sql, select, join, insert, temp

**Hi,**
I have a small problem of joining a temporary variable with a temporary table. Any input would be much appreciated. I present the problem in the order in which I have tried to solve it.

First of, I have a temporary variable which is created from a select statement.
The variable @enhet has 2 rows/observations (in my test file, later it will be many more):

```
declare @enhet varchar(50)

SELECT @enhet = 
     A.[EnhetsId]
FROM [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik] A
inner join (
            select [EnhetsId], max(SenastUppdaterad) as SenastDatum
            from [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik]
            group by [EnhetsId]
            ) B
on A.[EnhetsId] = B.[EnhetsId] and A.[SenastUppdaterad] = B.SenastDatum
WHERE [NyStatus] = 4
```

Secondly, I want to create a temporary table that combine these two observations (1 variable) with extra variables that are the same for both unique observations of variable @enhet. The aim is to have a table with unique values only for the variable @enhet but the rest is the same.

```
declare @temp2 table (
    EnhetsId varchar(50), 
    TjanstId Int, 
    Tabell varchar(50),
    Kommentar ntext,
    Uppdaterad datetime
)
insert into @temp2 (
    EnhetsId, TjanstId, Tabell, Kommentar, Uppdaterad) 
    values (
        @enhet, 1, 'GR_PS09_1', 'KLAR', getdate())

select * from @temp2
```

The problem is that when I run the script the output is only 1 row with just the last observation from the @enhet-variable.

Is there anyone who knows what to do? I have tried many things but since I am new to SQL I have failed to write the correct scripts. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance and best regards! 
:)

Comment: The variable `@enhet` does not have 2 rows/observations -- it is a scalar variable and can only hold 1 value.  You can verify by adding `SELECT @enhet` to the end of your first block of code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never thought of looking at SELECT @enhet, since I looked at the output before I added the "@enhet =" string. Thats why I failed to see the problem. Do you have any recommendation on how to make it work? I have tried make the first statement "@enhet" as a table instead of a (scalar) varialble, but still can´t figure out the right script to joint the two temporary tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to hold the results of your first joined query:

```
declare @temp2 table (
   EnhetsId varchar(50), 
   TjanstId Int, 
   Tabell varchar(50),
   Kommentar ntext,
   Uppdaterad datetime
);

WITH ENHET_CTE AS 
(
    SELECT A.[EnhetsId]
    FROM [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik] A
    inner join (
             select [EnhetsId], max(SenastUppdaterad) as SenastDatum
             from [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik]
             group by [EnhetsId]
             ) B
    on A.[EnhetsId] = B.[EnhetsId] and A.[SenastUppdaterad] = B.SenastDatum
    WHERE [NyStatus] = 4
)

insert into @temp2 
    (EnhetsId, TjanstId, Tabell, Kommentar, Uppdaterad) 
SELECT 
    EnhetsId, 1, 'GR_PS09_1', 'KLAR', getdate() 
from ENHET_CTE;

select * from @temp2;
```

Comment: thanks mr.Reband for the code, It worked perfectly. :)  Do you know how to add more conditions on top of the with ** (select..)-statement? I need to add a stored procedure, and given a certain condition I want the "insert into @temp2 " to execute.

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- you can encapsulate the entire block of code in a stored procedure.  What is the 'certain condition'?

Comment: I don´t want to change anything in the stored procedure since other programs are dependent upon them, but I want to add the condition that if the output from the SP (that I want to be executed in the code above) is "0" then go ahead with the insert statement (insert into @temp2).

Comment: Ok, I recommend submitting a new stack overflow question for that request -- there are several ways to accomplish that, none of which will look right buried in the comments here.

Comment: actually, I have just done that, I you wanna have a look, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072776/insert-text-into-table-conditional-on-values-returned-from-stored-procedures-an    Thanks for your help!